# How to remove Configuration option from WIKI for Power User?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

In my Liferay site, Power Users are getting permission for changing Configuration options like;  Look and Feel, Configuration and Export/Import options. I don't know how this is coming. Guessing that some permissions issue. But couldn't fix it. I didn't make any changes in Power User role. 
I just want to hide this Configuration option for Power user.

[image: The image is uploaded here... Please help..]

Comment: Can you ext your portal ? Or do you need a user-side portal administration only solution ?

Comment: Moreover, is the user in question (which is naturally in the power user group) the "owner" of the portlet (ie: is he the one who have put the portlet in the page) ?

Comment: Yes..I got it.. The portlet was added by that user only. I fixed it. Thanx a lot

Comment: @Shibu If possible, can you answer your own question and mark it as well, so that it would help others facing the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I tried to do it, but faced one problem. What I did is; Gave close permission for that user, and Logged with his user name and closed that portlet. Then logged in as admin, and added the same. But, still now, that option is coming for that user...!!! When I am creating new page and adding the portlet by admin, that option is not coming for that user.. So what should I do to make it work in the same page itself?

Comment: so is your problem solved or not? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portlet was added by that particular user. So that that configuration option is coming.. So if we don't want to give that permission, the portlet should be added by the admin.